# A way to pass cursor position to parboiled2 generated ast

Tags: peg, parboiled2

I 'm just wondering if it's possible to pass a `Position` of the cursor to AST. I have a strong feeling that it might be possible inside the `rule` macro but at the quick glace haven't found anything.

I need this to give more valuable error reporting on a type-checker phase.

Thanks!